# Configure OHS / Apache to support TLSv1 only

Tags: oracle, apache

We've running an old version of the Oracle HTTP Server (10.1.3.5).

With Chrome Version 45 the TLS 1.0 fallback was disabled which makes all our Oracle-APEX Application running via the OHS unreachable, 
as the OHS only supports TLS 1.0.

In the Blog-Entry (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/F6ZjP6FnyRE) announcing the removal of the TLS 1.0 fallback is stated:
"This will not break TLS 1.0 servers, only those which implement version negotiation incorrectly."

Now my question:
How can I configure the OHS/Apache correctly that it communicates to the Browser that it supports TLS 1.0 only?

We've already tried to set the SSLProtoll and SSLCipherSuite explicitly to TLS1:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite TLSv1
```

But with this configuration the Apache didn't start as the mod_ossl module used in the OHS doesn't support the alias TLSv1 for the SSLCipherSuite as documented under
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e10144/directives.htm#CIHGCJAB

Any help is very appreciated!!!

Thanks
Rudolf

Here is our current ssl.config:

```
    Listen 4459

    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

    SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

    SSLSessionCache        shmcb:<path to ohs>logs/ssl_scache(512000)
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

    SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1

    SSLMutex  file:<path to ohs>logs/ssl_mutex

    <VirtualHost _default_:4459>

    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "<path to ohs>htdocs"
    ServerName is-ora-10.noncd.rz.db.de
    ServerAdmin you@your.address
    ErrorLog <path to ohs>logs/error_log
    TransferLog <path to ohs>logs/access_log

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

    SSLWallet file:<path to ohs>conf/ssl.wlt/used_wallet

    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "<path to ohs>cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    SetEnvIf User-Agent "MSIE" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog <path to ohs>logs/ssl_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    </VirtualHost>                                  

    </IfDefine>
```

Comment: just a hint: there are better sites on stackexchange (perhaps even superuser.com) where you might find better answers for Apache questions